# How to add a random background image while creating a text image using php?

Tags: php, image, random, gd

I want to do something like that http://www.appline.ro/pasti Thx for helping

When refresh i want to show another image ,random image ,but I want to be able to write on it to get a final image http://2ol.us/scrie/lol.php.
 $image_file    ='image.png';  <<<< is a single image to show me how to do random images ,not know much programmer in php I apologize if you can help me and sorry for my bad english :(

```
    <?php   
            $font_file     = 'franklin.ttf';

            $image_file    = 'http://i642.photobucket.com/albums/uu143/paloma666/nature.png';






            // customizable variables
            $font_size = 47 ; // font size in pts
            $font_color = '#FF0000' ;

                // clean up the input
                if(empty($_GET['text']))    fatal_error('Error: No text specified.') ;
                $text = html_entity_decode($_GET['text']);
                //$text = floatval($text);
                //$text = number_format($text, 1, '.', '') . '%';

                if(empty($text))
                    fatal_error('Error: Text not properly formatted.') ;






                // x and y for the bottom right of the text
                // so it expands like right aligned text
                $x_finalpos     = 247;
                $y_finalpos     = 137;

                // trust me for now...in PNG out PNG

                $mime_type          = 'image/png' ;
                $extension          = '.png' ;
                $s_end_buffer_size  = 4096 ;

                // check for GD support
                if(!function_exists('ImageCreate'))
                    fatal_error('Error: Server does not support PHP image generation') ;

                // check font availability;
                if(!is_readable($font_file)) {
                    fatal_error('Error: The server is missing the specified font.') ;
                }

                // create and measure the text
                $font_rgb = hex_to_rgb($font_color) ;
                $box = @ImageTTFBBox($font_size,0,$font_file,$text) ;

                $text_width = abs($box[2]-$box[0]);
                $text_height = abs($box[5]-$box[3]);

                $image =  imagecreatefrompng($image_file);
                if(!$image || !$box)
                {
                    fatal_error('Error: The server could not create this image.') ;
                }

                // allocate colors and measure final text position
                $font_color = ImageColorAllocate($image,$font_rgb['red'],$font_rgb['green'],$font_rgb['blue']) ;
                $image_width = imagesx($image);
                $put_text_x = $image_width - $text_width - ($image_width - $x_finalpos);
                $put_text_y = $y_finalpos;

                // Write the text
                imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $put_text_x,  $put_text_y, $font_color, $font_file, $text);

                header("Content-type: $mime_type");
                ImagePNG($image) ;
                ImageDestroy($image) ;
                exit ;

                /*
                    attempt to create an image containing the error message given. 
                    if this works, the image is sent to the browser. if not, an error
                    is logged, and passed back to the browser as a 500 code instead.
                */

                function fatal_error($message)
                {
                    // send an image
                    if(function_exists('ImageCreate'))
                    {
                        $width = ImageFontWidth(5) * strlen($message) + 10 ;
                        $height = ImageFontHeight(5) + 10 ;
                        if($image = ImageCreate($width,$height))
                        {
                            $background = ImageColorAllocate($image,255,255,255) ;
                            $text_color = ImageColorAllocate($image,0,0,0) ;
                            ImageString($image,5,5,5,$message,$text_color) ;    
                            header('Content-type: image/png') ;
                            ImagePNG($image) ;
                            ImageDestroy($image) ;
                            exit ;
                        }
                    }

                    // send 500 code
                    header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error") ;
                    print($message) ;
                    exit ;
                }

                /* 
                    decode an HTML hex-code into an array of R,G, and B values.
                    accepts these formats: (case insensitive) #ffffff, ffffff, #fff, fff 
                */    

                function hex_to_rgb($hex) {
                    // remove '#'
                    if(substr($hex,0,1) == '#')
                        $hex = substr($hex,1) ;

                    // expand short form ('fff') color to long form ('ffffff')
                    if(strlen($hex) == 3) {
                        $hex = substr($hex,0,1) . substr($hex,0,1) .
                               substr($hex,1,1) . substr($hex,1,1) .
                               substr($hex,2,1) . substr($hex,2,1) ;
                    }

                    if(strlen($hex) != 6)
                        fatal_error('Error: Invalid color "'.$hex.'"') ;

                    // convert from hexidecimal number systems
                    $rgb['red'] = hexdec(substr($hex,0,2)) ;
                    $rgb['green'] = hexdec(substr($hex,2,2)) ;
                    $rgb['blue'] = hexdec(substr($hex,4,2)) ;

                    return $rgb ;
                }
            ?>





 <?php   
            $font_file     = 'franklin.ttf';

 $image_file    ='http://i642.photobucket.com/albums/uu143/paloma666/nature.png';

            // customizable variables
            $font_size = 47 ; // font size in pts
            $font_color = '#FF0000' ;

                // clean up the input
                if(empty($_GET['text']))    fatal_error('Error: No text specified.') ;
                $text = html_entity_decode($_GET['text']);
                //$text = floatval($text);
                //$text = number_format($text, 1, '.', '') . '%';

                if(empty($text))
                    fatal_error('Error: Text not properly formatted.') ;






                // x and y for the bottom right of the text
                // so it expands like right aligned text
                $x_finalpos     = 247;
                $y_finalpos     = 137;

                // trust me for now...in PNG out PNG

                $mime_type          = 'image/png' ;
                $extension          = '.png' ;
                $s_end_buffer_size  = 4096 ;

                // check for GD support
                if(!function_exists('ImageCreate'))
                    fatal_error('Error: Server does not support PHP image generation') ;

                // check font availability;
                if(!is_readable($font_file)) {
                    fatal_error('Error: The server is missing the specified font.') ;
                }

                // create and measure the text
                $font_rgb = hex_to_rgb($font_color) ;
                $box = @ImageTTFBBox($font_size,0,$font_file,$text) ;

                $text_width = abs($box[2]-$box[0]);
                $text_height = abs($box[5]-$box[3]);

                $image =  imagecreatefrompng($image_file);
                if(!$image || !$box)
                {
                    fatal_error('Error: The server could not create this image.') ;
                }

                // allocate colors and measure final text position
                $font_color = ImageColorAllocate($image,$font_rgb['red'],$font_rgb['green'],$font_rgb['blue']) ;
                $image_width = imagesx($image);
                $put_text_x = $image_width - $text_width - ($image_width - $x_finalpos);
                $put_text_y = $y_finalpos;

                // Write the text
                imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $put_text_x,  $put_text_y, $font_color, $font_file, $text);

                header("Content-type: $mime_type");
                ImagePNG($image) ;
                ImageDestroy($image) ;
                exit ;

                /*
                    attempt to create an image containing the error message given. 
                    if this works, the image is sent to the browser. if not, an error
                    is logged, and passed back to the browser as a 500 code instead.
                */

                function fatal_error($message)
                {
                    // send an image
                    if(function_exists('ImageCreate'))
                    {
                        $width = ImageFontWidth(5) * strlen($message) + 10 ;
                        $height = ImageFontHeight(5) + 10 ;
                        if($image = ImageCreate($width,$height))
                        {
                            $background = ImageColorAllocate($image,255,255,255) ;
                            $text_color = ImageColorAllocate($image,0,0,0) ;
                            ImageString($image,5,5,5,$message,$text_color) ;    
                            header('Content-type: image/png') ;
                            ImagePNG($image) ;
                            ImageDestroy($image) ;
                            exit ;
                        }
                    }

                    // send 500 code
                    header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error") ;
                    print($message) ;
                    exit ;
                }

                /* 
                    decode an HTML hex-code into an array of R,G, and B values.
                    accepts these formats: (case insensitive) #ffffff, ffffff, #fff, fff 
                */    

                function hex_to_rgb($hex) {
                    // remove '#'
                    if(substr($hex,0,1) == '#')
                        $hex = substr($hex,1) ;

                    // expand short form ('fff') color to long form ('ffffff')
                    if(strlen($hex) == 3) {
                        $hex = substr($hex,0,1) . substr($hex,0,1) .
                               substr($hex,1,1) . substr($hex,1,1) .
                               substr($hex,2,1) . substr($hex,2,1) ;
                    }

                    if(strlen($hex) != 6)
                        fatal_error('Error: Invalid color "'.$hex.'"') ;

                    // convert from hexidecimal number systems
                    $rgb['red'] = hexdec(substr($hex,0,2)) ;
                    $rgb['green'] = hexdec(substr($hex,2,2)) ;
                    $rgb['blue'] = hexdec(substr($hex,4,2)) ;

                    return $rgb ;
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please reformat your code, removing anything unrelated to the problem, and separating files into their own code block.

Answer (score 1):

One possiblity would be to have an array of possible images and then generate a random index.

Could be something like this:

```
$array = array("example.com/image1.png","example.com/image2.png","example.com/image3.png");
$index = rand(0,count($array)-1);
$image_file = $array[$index];
```

I haven't tested the code, but it should work :)

Comment: Seems like Marco Bernardini was a bit faster :D

Answer (score 1):

Make an array containing some images, or links to them, and pick them using the `array_rand()` function.

See https://php.net/array_rand